# Cannot access data from JSON receiving title is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to access the below JSON data:
[image]

I want to access the title key inside food_report but when I write
console.log(response.data.content.food_report.title)
am receiving title is undefined

Any idea where am going wrong? Any help would be appreciated

The complete code that I have used is :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header.native';
import HeaderW from './components/Header.web';
import {timestamp, getFullDate} from '../../utils/dateUtils';
import {vc} from '../../api';
import {API} from '../../api';

export default function TodaysGoalScreen(props) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const [data_web, getDataweb] = useState({});
  const [data_mob, getDataMob] = useState({});
  const [width, getWidth] = useState('');
  const SetWidth = () => {
    getWidth(window.screen.availWidth);
  };
  const getdataweb = async () => {
    try {
      const id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
      const response = await API.get(
        `/nutrition/nutri-plan?child_id=${id}&event_date=${timestamp}&vc=${vc}`,
      );
      console.log('response', response.data.content);
      getDataweb(response.data.content);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  const getdatanative = async () => {
    try {
      const id = props.route.params.id;
      const response = await API.get(
        `/nutrition/nutri-plan?child_id=${id}&event_date=${timestamp}&vc=${vc}`,
      );
      console.log('res', response.data.content);
      getDataMob(response.data.content);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS == 'web') {
      getdataweb();
    } else {
      getdatanative();
    }
    SetWidth();
    setInterval(SetWidth, 1000);
  }, []);
  const web_data = data_web;
  const web_mob = data_mob;
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5', flex: 1}}>
      {Platform.OS == 'web' ? (
        <View>
          <HeaderW data={data_web} />
          <View
            style={
              width > 414 ? styles.todaysgoalcardweb : styles.todaysgoalcardmob
            }>
            {data_web &&
              data_web != '' &&
              data_web != undefined &&
              data_web != null &&
              console.log('aaa', data_web.food_report.title)}
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Header data={data_mob} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  todaysgoalcardweb: {
    height: '393px',
    width: '600px',
    marginTop: '8px',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffff',
    padding: 10,
  },
  todaysgoalcardmob: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '360px',
    height: '293px',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
  todaysgoaltitle: {},
});
```

added the above code to provide better clarity hopefully it would help

Comment: What's data in `response.data.content` showing in log?

Comment: are you consoling response.data.content?

Comment: The error is telling you that, ***at the time of execution***, `response.data.content.food_report` is undefined. Where in the react component lifecycle are you attempting to log this response value? Please update your question to include a full [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: Hi @NooruddinLakhani have added the complete code kindly check if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is your initial `data_web` and `data_mob` state are empty objects

```
const [data_web, getDataweb] = useState({});
const [data_mob, getDataMob] = useState({});
```

but you attempt to access a deeply nested property on the initial render

```
{data_web &&               // <-- data_web defined so truthy value
  data_web != '' &&        // <-- data_web is object so true
  data_web != undefined && // <-- data_web defined so true
  data_web != null &&      // <-- data_web is object so again true
  console.log('aaa', data_web.food_report.title)} // <-- blow up because data_web.food_report is undefined
```

Can't access `title` property because `data_web.food_report` is undefined.

## Solution

Use optional chaining if that is available to you

```
{console.log('aaa', data_web.food_report?.title)}
```

Use conventional null checks for each nested level that is potentially undefined

```
{data_web.food_report &&
  data_web.food_report.title &&
  console.log('aaa', data_web.food_report.title)
}
```